# I am trying to set-up MFA for an AWS user in the organization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, policy

```
       {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1506369084151",
      "Action": [
        "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
        "iam:EnableMFADevice",
        "iam:ListMFADevices",
        "iam:ResyncMFADevice"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::account_#:user/user_name"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have this above policy which should enable users to set-up MFA by themselves. 
However, when I test this policy (by logging in as one of the users, I am not able to perform the desired action)

What am I missing in the policy snippet?

PS: The policy is attached to the user I try to log-in as. So this silly mistake is ruled out.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "not able to perform the desired action"? What are you doing, and what error is displayed?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am trying to set-up an IAM policy so that the user can himself/herself configure MFA for his/her account. 
There is no error displayed while validating the policy, just that the policy does not work. So the user is not able to set-up MFA.

Comment: What are they clicking when they try to setup MFA? What is shown on screen? Are the buttons available? Are any error messages displayed? Please provide more information than "not able to set-up MFA".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowEnableResyncDeleteListMFA",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
        "iam:EnableMFADevice",
        "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
        "iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iam::AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:mfa/${aws:username}",
        "arn:aws:iam::AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:user/${aws:username}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowDeactivateMFA",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:DeactivateMFADevice"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iam::AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:mfa/${aws:username}",
        "arn:aws:iam::AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:user/${aws:username}"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": true
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:ListMFADevices",
        "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
        "iam:ListUsers"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: for this to work, I will have to first allow IAM ReadOnly or IAMFullAccess to the user(s) profile?

Comment: No, no need to allow anything else because in my policy that already allow it

Comment: Thank you. It work's for me.

We can also add this part to enforce MFA setup before user starts using any other services.

`{
  "Sid": "DoNotAllowAnythingOtherThanAboveUnlessMFAd",
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "NotAction": "iam:*",
  "Resource": "*",
  "Condition": {
  "Null": {
  "aws:MultiFactorAuthAge": "true"
    }
   }
  }`

Comment: Do not need to specific deny on other aws resource because default of IAM policy is deny all. In this case, user just have permission to modify their MFA. You can test it.